# Implementing timer callback in c

Tags: c, linux, timer, callback

I am new to callback functions in C. I want to create a timed callback.

Scenario: I want a timer function which will trigger the callback function when timer expires. For example, every 5 sec the timer expires and calls the function.

How should I approach this problem ?

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? How did (or didn't) it work? Is there something more specific that you have problems with, or wondering about (like e.g. function pointer, timers, threads, or something else)?

Comment: Actually i need  a program which will send beacon frames from my wifi adapter for syncronisation...So i need to send beacon frames every 5 secs....in between ,im sending some other data! ... so the timer function should not block it until its 5 sec....
i tired by checking the time before sending each packets ...but its not an efficient way

Comment: Does it have to be every five second *exactly*? Or is it okay with *about* every five second? Because if it's okay with about every five seconds, then you have a good solution (when you send another packet, check if it's at least five seconds since you last sent the special packet).

Comment: Otherwise you can implement timers using threads or `SIGALRM`, but that add other problems and complications (like you needing synchronization, message queues or special flags).

Comment: I need EXACTLY 5 seconds ... i mean like an interpet every 5sec with high priority....So when the timer expries this interput will call the function for sync ..
i hope you understand !

Comment: SIGALRM... any good documentation i reed about it... i didnt find some examples or documentation...Any suggestion ?

Comment: Start by reading [the `alarm` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html), then continue with the functions in the manual pages see also section, for example [`setitimer`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html). There are *thousands* of examples using both methods available through a simple search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **How should you approach this problem?**

As with all problems:

- Figure out what you want to do precisely
- Ask yourself how you would do it yourself if you needed to (and if you could)
- Try to formalize previous step as close as possible to single statements sentences, one step at a time.
- Identify what blocks you / what you don't know how to do. Do some research on that.

**What you want to do precisely**

You want to "create a timed callback". I think this means :

- You have a function `foo` doing some work
- You have your program running
- You want to be able to say "From right now, in *X* miliseconds, call `foo`" anywhere in your program

**How would you do this yourself?**

I think you would, for example, launch a stopwatch with *X* miliseconds then keep doing whatever you were doing. When the stopwatch reaches zero, you stop what you do and do the thing needed. Finally, resume what you were doing.

**What blocks you?**

Judging by your question I think two things block you:

- You need to understand how to do function callbacks in C. See "function pointers"
- You need to understand how to have a timer and do something when the timer reaches zero.

A few google searches will help you with both.